# Invalid DOB on Newsletter Submission?

Tags: newsletter, magento1.9.2.4

I have an issue on a website where if I enter in an email address in the newsletter sign-up field, it fails to submit and says 'There was a problem with the subscription: Please enter a valid date of birth.'

It's using the default Magento newsletter functionality so I'm confused as to why this could be happening. It's on Magento ver. 1.9.2.4.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This error is catch on this file, line 73 :

> src/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php

Put some debug before, in the 'try{}' to get more details.
Hope that help you.